# Magnetic Pendulum Experiment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

Suppose we have a pendulum which is fixed at some point, P. We release it from some initial angle $\theta$ and it swings over a solenoid for which there exists some magnetic force. Note that there is a piece of string connecting from one end at a fixed point P, and the mass being swung is a small magnet at the other end.

[image: Apparatus]

If I wish to model this pendulum's motion, I believe that I cannot use the generic formula;
$$y(t)=Ae^{-kt}cos(\omega t)$$ 
I believe that a more refined model may be required which includes the effect of such a magnetic field on the mass.

However, deriving this is seeming to be very difficult for me... Is there a possible way where we can include the effect of the magnetic field on the original mechanical system?

I have attempted to make an ODE in such a way that;
$$y''+\alpha y'+\beta y=0$$
Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just constants caused by friction.
After further thought I have attempted to make an ODE by considering the equation;

$$I(\omega^2)''=\tau_{gravity}+\tau_{Dampening}+\tau_{Magnetic} $$

Would this be on the right track? Or is there another path which I need to take?

Comment: Have you established what the force between magnet and solenoid is? And what are the $\sigma$ representing?

Comment: You cannot, for reasonable definitions. But I don't think that's what you mean. I think you mean "some simple formula like this"? If so, consider standard treatments generally ignore friction for clarity.

Comment: I'm more concerned about adding another term to the original ODE. But I don't know what the term should be... That way I account for the magnetic field strength.